# How to find records from Database where column_name != some_value?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

In flask, I have defined a model where the columns are like id,name,status, etc.
And the status value can be -1, 0 ,1,2,.... (-1 is allowed for -ve number except that all are +ve numbers)
I want to find count of all the records where the status is not equal to -1.
or I can say count of all records where status is greater than equal to 0.

what I have tried is, I am writing code as -

`Modelname.query.filter_by(status!= -1).count() 
or 
Modelname.query.filter_by(status >= 0).count()`

But I am getting error like status is not defined in both the cases as filter_by doesn't support != and I have tried with only filter but got same error and if I use status= -1 then I'm not getting this error.

Comment: `Modelname.query.filter(Modelname.status != -1).count()`

Comment: @ Doobeh  Thank you so much, This solved my problem.